# Why does the generic bound "E implements I" result in a compiler error?

Tags: java, generics

Why does this compile:

```
class MaxMin<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
   E max=null;
   E min=null;
}
```

...but this doesn't?

```
class MaxMin<E implements Comparable<E>>
{
   E max=null;
   E min=null;
}
```

Comment: post the compilation errors as well..

Comment: comparable is not an interface?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory, [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is an interface.

Comment: -1 For not posting the compiler error message. It answers this question, as well as makes it more searchable.

Answer (score 15):

Generic type bounds only specify `extends` and `super`.

Quoting the [Java Generics Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)(*emphasis mine*)

> To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name,
>   followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound, which in
>   this example is Number. **Note that, in this context, extends is used in
>   a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or
>   "implements" (as in interfaces)**